# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de mostrar el valor de una variable dentro de una funcion?

Tags: html, reactjs, funciones

estoy intentando hacer una pagina consumiendo una API con react, pero me surgio la duda de: **¿Cual es la forma correcta de mostrar el valor de una variable en react?**

Se que se puede hacer algo como:

`<h2>{variable}</h2>`

Pero al estar dentro de una funcion, no me deja hacer eso, lo tengo tal que asi:

```
  const callback = (res) => {
    const htmlCity = document.getElementById('city-name') 
    let cityName = res.data.name //Esta es la variable que quiero mostrar
    htmlCity.innerHTML = `City: ${cityName}`

}
```

Y el html tal que asi:

`<h2 id="city-name">City: </h2>`

Muchas gracias por su respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React` funciona en base a estados que pueden modificarse por alguna razón. Esos estados deben ser controlados para que React pueda trabajar con ellos.

Por lo que si necesitas crear una variable, y dicha variable va a cambiar a los largo del flujo - *ya sea porque depende del valor de un input, de un select o algun elemento del DOM* -, necesitas crear un estado que controle el cambio de esa variable.

Para tu caso sería

```
const [city, setCity] = useState("");

const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
   setCity(value);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Ciudad: {city}</h1>
    <input value={city} onChange={handleChange} />
  </div>
);
```

Donde mediante el hooks **[useState](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)**, controlamos el estado de nuestro elemento, y en la función `handleChange`, le asignamos el valor ingresado en el input a dicho estado mediante `setCity`. Finalmente solo muestras la variable como ya sabes hacerlo.

Si tienes alguna duda, nos comentas

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero no sabria como afecta target en la funcion, estoy intentando hacerlo al pie de la letra pero me dice que target es undefined

Comment: @HatoriHanso Podrías pasarle un event entonces -> `const handleChange = event => { setCity(event.target.value) }` debería bastar

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"; 

const App = () => {

  const [ city, setCity ] = useState("City-1")

  return(
    <div>
      <h2> City: { city }</h2>
      
      <input onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value) } />
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Te invito a leer [answer]. Cuando respondas una pregunta y coloques código, por favor explica el funcionamiento del mismo, puedes apoyarte con documentación y/o con comentarios adicionales, de este modo tu respuesta tendrá mejor utilidad tanto para el OP como para futuros visitantes.

Comment: Hola Andres, muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta pero no es lo que buscaba, mi pregunta es como mostrar una variable que se genera o guarda dentro de una funcion

Answer (score 0):

lo mejor que puede hacer es usar useState que es un Hook para el estado en este caso de la constante y le puede dar un valor inicial como en el ejemplo o en blanco y enviarle el dato en este caso con un input a `setCityName`, así quedo el código, espero sea de ayuda.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState("Bogotá");

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{cityName}</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```